# ManagementException: Provider Load Failure Error when accessing Win32_NetworkAdapter

Tags: c#, wmi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I resolve a “Provider load failure” for WMI requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563150/how-can-i-resolve-a-provider-load-failure-for-wmi-requests)

Whenver I try to access the `Win32_NetworkAdapter` table I get the following exception:

> System.Management.ManagementException: Provider Load Failure Error

This is how I tried to access it:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
  @"SELECT *  FROM   Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE  Manufacturer != 'Microsoft' " + 
   "AND NOT PNPDeviceID LIKE 'ROOT\\%'");

var managementObjectList = mos.Get();

// Exception:
foreach (var networkAdapter in managementObjectList)
{
}
```

This way I get an exception too:

```
ManagementClass mgmt = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapter");
using (ManagementObjectCollection objCol = mgmt.GetInstances())
{
    // Exception:
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in objCol)
    {
    }
}
```

I am also gettings the same error when I try to open the instances of `Win32_NetworkAdapter` using [WMI CIM Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24045)

What could be the cause of this and how can I make this reliably work?