# ManagementException - "Provider failure" - what is this?

Tags: c#, wmi

Somebody Else's Code says:

```
var wmiNetAdapterConfiguration = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
var wmiNetAdapters = wmiNetAdapterConfiguration.GetInstances();
var count = wmiNetAdapters.Count; // throws exception
```

This bombs in my dev environment with `System.Management.ManagementException`: "Provider failure".

The original author is not available for questioning, and I have no idea what this means, or why it is failing in my environment.  Help please!

Comment: Check out the following SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563150/how-can-i-resolve-a-provider-load-failure-for-wmi-requests

Answer (score 0):

This error also occur if you're connecting to a remote machine, authenticating using a local account (local to the remote machine!), and UAC is enabled.  Setting per-namespace permissions might help, depends on the WMI namespace I suspect.  Disabling UAC should resolve it.